# VBScript Error - Object Required ObjTSO

Tags: vbscript

```
'========================================================================
'## Global Object and Variable Settings
'======================================================================== 

Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strSystemDrive: strSystemDrive = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")

'========================================================================
'## Main Code 
'========================================================================

 'On Error Resume Next

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'## Script Variables 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strFolder: strFolder = strSystemDrive & "\Endpoint Reboot Info"
Dim strFile: strFile = strSystemDrive & "\Endpoint Reboot Info\Endpoint_Reboot_Logfile.txt" 
strcurrentDateTime = Now()
 Dim string0: string0 = "Endpoint restart analysis initialized"
Dim string1: string1 = "Calculating the endpoint uptime .. If greater than 14 days, machine will be restarted"
Dim string2: string2 = "Warning: The current OS Uptime exceeds 14 days! This system will be rebooted!"
 Dim string3: string3 = " As the current OS Uptime is less than 14 days, this system will NOT be rebooted currently"
Dim string4: string4 = "This system will restart now!"
Dim string5: string5 = "User has clicked cancel, hence PC was NOT restarted"
Dim string6: string6 = "User has clicked OK. Restarting PC now.."

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'## Code for creating the folder and file necessary for logging and initializing the log file
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Function CreateLogFile(filename)
Dim f: set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 8, True)
f.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string0  
f.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string1
Set CreateLogFile = f
End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'## Code for checking endpoint OS uptime and force restarting post message display to end user
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim objTSO: Set objTSO = CreateLogFile(strFile) 
 strComputer = "." 
Const FOR_APPENDING = 8

SET objWMIDateTime = CREATEOBJECT("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
SET objWMI = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
SET colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
FOR EACH objOS in colOS
objWMIDateTime.Value = objOS.LastBootUpTime 
objTSO.WriteLine "Last Boot Up Time: " & objWMIDateTime.GetVarDate & vbcrlf & _
    "System Up Time: " &  TimeSpan(objWMIDateTime.GetVarDate,NOW) & _
    " (hh:mm:ss)"
NEXT

FUNCTION TimeSpan(dt1, dt2) 
' Function to display the difference between
' 2 dates in hh:mm:ss format
IF (ISDATE(dt1) AND ISDATE(dt2)) = FALSE THEN 
    TimeSpan = "00:00:00" 
    EXIT FUNCTION 
    END IF 

    seconds = ABS(DATEDIFF("S", dt1, dt2)) 
    minutes = seconds \ 60 
    hours = minutes \ 60 
    minutes = minutes MOD 60 
    seconds = seconds MOD 60 

    IF LEN(hours) = 1 THEN hours = "0" & hours 

    TimeSpan = hours & ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & minutes, 2) & ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & seconds, 2) 


If (hours > 336) Then
    f.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string2
    Dim retval: retval = InputBox("Warning!: The current OS Uptime exceeds 14 days! This system will be rebooted! Please save ALL of your work and ONLY then click OK")
    If IsEmpty(retval) Then
            msgbox ("User has terminated the action by clicking cancel")
        objTSO.WriteLine string5                
    Else 
        objTSO.WriteLine string6            
        WshShell.Run "shutdown.exe -R -T 0"             
    End If  

Else
    WScript.Sleep 10000 
    strcurrentDateTime = Now()  
    objTSO.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & string3       
    WScript.Quit
End If
f.Close()
END FUNCTION 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'## End of code/VB Script
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have now put up the full script as suggested. Please help with below queries:

1. This Line is not getting written into the log file

   ```
   objTSO.WriteLine "Last Boot Up Time: " & objWMIDateTime.GetVarDate & vbcrlf & _
       "System Up Time: " &  TimeSpan(objWMIDateTime.GetVarDate,NOW) & _
       " (hh:mm:ss)"
   ```
2. Also please check the logic of the code by changing the (hours>336) condition. This script will be executed locally on the machines, so instead of the previous reboot function, i have now modified it to WshShell.Run "shutdown.exe -R -T 0"

Please guide! Thanks!!

Comment: Your 3rd point is unrelated to the other 2 points and I think you need the [`SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277311.aspx) to be able to do this.

Comment: Would you kindly refrain from destroying the formatting every time you update your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `CreateLogFile` creates/opens the file, but then closes it right away:

```
Function CreateLogFile()
    If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
        Set objTSO = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, FOR_APPENDING)
        objTSO.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string0
        objTSO.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string1
        objTSO.Close()
    Else
        objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFile)
        Set objTSO = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, FOR_APPENDING)
        objTSO.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string0
        objTSO.WriteLine strcurrentDateTime & " " & string1
        objTSO.Close()
    End If
End Function
```

meaning that when the function returns the file handle is already closed, causing all subsequent attempts to write to the file (without opening it again) to fail.

What you actually want to do is change your function to something like this:

```
Function CreateLogFile(filename)
    Dim f : Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, True)
    f.WriteLine Now & " " & string0
    f.WriteLine Now & " " & string1
    Set CreateLogFile = f
End Function

Dim objTSO : Set objTSO = CreateLogFile(strFile)

...

objTSO.Close   'at the end of the script
```

Setting the 3rd parameter of the `OpenTextFile` method to `True` causes it to create the file in case it's missing.

Comment: Even after changing like above also, the point 1 line is still not getting written into log file.

Comment: @ShrutiPramod Check if your WMI query actually returns a result (`WScript.Echo colOS.Count`). Also, you cannot use `f` outside the function `CreateLogFile` like you did in line 78.

Comment: Yes @Ansgar, I checked that (WScript.Echo colOS.Count) is returning 1.
Also, i removed f outside the createLogFile function and replaced it with objTSO but i get the object variable not set error.

Comment: That's not possible. Please make sure you're actually running the script you think you are, e.g. by adding a line `WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptFullName` at the beginning of your script.